# Symfony 4 file permissions of var directory change every time

Tags: symfony, file-permissions, symfony4

I am setting up a new server and installed **Ubuntu 18.04** in combination with **Apache2**. My project is stored in `/var/www/project`. In **apache2.conf** I added

```
<Directory /var/www/project/>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

In my virtualhosts file I point to `/var/www/project/public`
When I go to the Ip address of my server I see my project and everything works, except one thing:

whenever I clear the cache with `php bin/console cache:clear` the permissions of my directory `var` are messed up which results in errors in the production environment.

I can fix this with:

```
chmod -R 777 var/
```

But the problem returns wheneven I clear the cache again. I tried with different users including `root`, but always the same problem. I do not understand what is causing this. In the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/setup/file_permissions.html) on file permissions it says:

> In Symfony `3.x`, you needed to do some extra work to make sure that your cache directory was writable. But that is no longer true! In Symfony `4`, everything works automatically

Well not for me, but what could cause the problem?

Comment: Had the same problem but on CentOS... is there any SELinux guards activated?

Comment: @AndrewShmig, no none...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The problem

The cache directory is owned by the user executing the `cache:clear` command.

- Lets say your project files are owned by `www-data`.
- Clearing the cache with root user
- Cache is owned by root
- `www-data` can't write in cache directory

## Solution

execute cache:clear using the user owning the files.

- Login as www-data: `su www-data -s /bin/bash`
- clear the cache `./bin/console cache:clear`

> Depending on your settings, your `www-data` user may be different

Comment: I thought this could be the case, but it wasn't. The user owning the directory and the user clearing the cache were the same. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu and now it somehow works.

Comment: I am not starting to get you were right. After clearing the cache as user `dirk` the server could no longer write to `cache/prod`. When I logged in as `www-data` there was one issue: i could not change back to myself. So now what I do is run `sudo -u www-data php bin/console cache:clear`. But maybe there is also a solution where I can do this as user `dirk`?

Comment: See https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html . Looks like we have XY problem. Why do you need to clear the cache?

Answer (score 4):

The solution that worked for me (using Symfony 3.x and Ubuntu 18.04) is the one explained in the official site, here:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd

Maybe that solution work also with Symfony 4?

Extract:

> **3. Using ACL on a System that Supports setfacl (Linux/BSD)**
>
> Most Linux and BSD distributions don't support `chmod +a`, but do
>   support another utility called `setfacl`. You may need to install
>   `setfacl` and enable `ACL` support on your disk partition before using it.
>   Then, use the following script to determine your web server user and
>   grant the needed permissions:
>
> `HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E
>   '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1
>   | cut -d\  -f1)`
>
> `sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var`
>
> `sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var`
>
> Note:
>   The first setfacl command sets permissions for future files and
>   folders, while the second one sets permissions on the existing files
>   and folders. Both of these commands assign permissions for the system
>   user and the Apache user.
>   setfacl isn't available on NFS mount points. However, storing cache
>   and logs over NFS is strongly discouraged for performance reasons.

Personal hint:

`sudo apt-get install setfacl` may says "unable to find setfacl".

If so:

- check if setfacl is present: `setfacl -h`
- setfacl is part of the `acl` package, so install `acl` if missed

Answer (score 0):

It took me quite a while to solve the problem in Symfony 4.4 that only was present in PROD but not in DEV. I still don't know what difference between PROD and DEV caused it, however. At least it's working now.

If ACL is present, the first solution in https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/setup/file_permissions.html#permissions-required-by-symfony-applications should work. I just manually set the `HTTPDUSER` since the given code returned the wrong one. Else, setting the permissions after every single `cache:clear` should do the job, too:

```
sudo chown -R "$local_user":"$webserver_group" "$app_dir/var/"
sudo chmod -R 0777 "$app_dir/var/"
```

Maybe you have to manually delete old files in var/ bevore first by `rm -rf var/*`